# Extract specific urls from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi4

From given `HTML` I need to extract specific urls. For example, `<a>` and attribute `href` looks like this:

```
<a href="https://hoster.com/some_description-specific_name-more_description.html">
```

I need to extract only urls that include "hoster.com" and "specific_name"

I have used `BeautifulSoup` on an Raspberry Pi but i only can the basic thing which extracts all ULRs of an `HTML`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("page.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select your elements more specific with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('a[href*="hoster.com"][href*="specific_name"]')
```

But in case that multiple patterns has to match I would recommend:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if all(s in link['href'] for s in pattern):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

###### Example

```
html = '''
<a href="https://hoster.com/some_description-specific_name-more_description.html">
<a href="https://lobster.com/some_description-specific_name-more_description.html">
<a href="https://hipster.com/some_description-specific_name-more_description.html">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pattern = ['hoster.com','specific_name']

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if all(s in link['href'] for s in pattern):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

###### Output

```
https://hoster.com/some_description-specific_name-more_description.html
```